# Is there a Windows driver function that does the equivalent of the Windows file api SeFileAttributes

Tags: c++, windows, driver

My question is if there's a Windows Driver function that does the equivalent of the function SetFileAttributesA in the Windows file api. If there is I would like to know where its located in the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: I don't think there is a native C++ lib for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887398/setting-file-attributes-by-using-c-c-native-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "Windows Driver" function you mean a function you can call from/in Kernel Mode code, then yes, there is one.

The function is `ZwSetInformationFile()` - defined in `wdm.h` as follows:

```
NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ZwSetInformationFile(__in HANDLE FileHandle, __out PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    __in_bcount(Length) PVOID FileInformation, __in ULONG Length, __in FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass);
```

You will need to set the `FileInformationClass` parameter to `FileAttributeTagInformation` with the `FileInformation` parameter pointing to a `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TAG_INFORMATION` structure.

More information/documentation can be found here [ZwSetInformationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwsetinformationfile) and here [FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TAG_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_attribute_tag_information).

Hope this helps.

Comment: File systems that don't support reparse points may not support `FileAttributeTagInformation` at all. Instead use [`FileBasicInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_basic_information) with the timestamps zeroed so they're ignored.